# Time to buy a house without a mortgage equation!!

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I am looking into a "real world" calculation to calculate the time taken for someone to buy their own home while they rent it. They do this by buying small pieces of the property every month, and progressively earning a larger percentage of their rent back as their ownership level grows.

For example, if the house price (p) is £40,000 , the gross rent ( gr - rent paid by tenant ) is £550, the net rent ( nr - profit made by owner after costs ) is £400. This is a standard rental agreement with the owner making £400 a month.
If we now give the tenant the option to buy a piece of the property every month and earn back a percentage of this net rent. In our example the tenant could pay a small deposit(d) of £2,500 to start off the agreement and then agree to pay £100 a month as capital repayment(c) to buy the house.

So at the start of the program month(m) = 0, our tenant owns £2,500 of the property which is 6.25%. They pay their gross rent (gr) of £550, and capital repayment(c) of £100. Because they own 6.25% of the property, they receive 6.25% of the net rent (nr) which is £25, this is added to the capital repayment and used to buy more of the house.

month(m) 1 starts with the tenant owning £2,625 ( 6.56% ), they pay gr=£550 c=£100 plus 6.56% of nr (£400) which is £26.25

month(m) 2 ownership=£2751.25 ( 6.88% ) etc.....

I have written a program that calculates the figures month by month, much as I have done above, to calculate the length of time in months it takes for the tenant to buy 100% of the property. This is a rather exciting 140 months ( 11 years 8 months )!! But obviously I would like to clean this up and have a single equation using the variables I have outlined above:

months(m) price(p) deposit(d) gross rent(gr) net rent(nr) capital repayment(c) and possibly ownership (o)

To calculate how many months(m) before ownership(o) >= price(p)-deposit(d)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is for an actual social housing project so your work would be going to a good cause!

Comment: Irrelevant question; Is this a real procedure to buy a house?

Comment: So hopefully I have this straight: this basically allows for person take make annuity payment (rent payments)  that have a decreasing growth rate (since gain a percent of the house each year and pay less rent)with this accomponied by constant payments of capita repayments?

Comment: UserX - This is a real project I am working on that will enable people to buy a house without a loan.

Comment: Kamster - Not quite, the gross rent (gr) that they pay is constant, as is their capital repayment (c), the only thing that changes is the amount of the property that the tenant owns, and thus the % of the net rent (nr) that gets added to the capital repayment each month. So the effect is a compound growth in ownership resulting in much shorter times than you'd expect to buy the property.

Comment: also are you treating price of the house as a fixed price so there are present value calculations within the problem? What I mean by that is that are we assuming that the house of 40,000 now is still worth 40,000 many years down the line so tenant just has to pay of that amount

Comment: let $r_t=$ % of ownership at time t. If I understand this problem correctly you want to know at what $t$ does $r_t=1 $ is that correct?

Comment: Kamster - For the moment we are treating the price of the house as fixed, as I didn't want to get into the complexity of adding a monthly price increase % onto both the house, and the amount (monetary value) of the house owned by the tenant, although obviously the % ownership would remain the same.

Comment: Kamster - Yes ( sorry I can't do the code properly on here yet!), we are look for the value of t where ownership is 100%.
As this is 'Real World' situation t should be an integer, and we are looking for the lowest value of t where ownership is greater than or equal to 100%. As in the final month, the tenant will have to complete the purchase of their home, but may get a rebate of some of their capital repayment for that month.

Comment: so if $r_t=$ % ownership. Then we are looking for t when $r_t=1 , we can round up to get the real world time in months.

Comment: so I tried to find an explicit answer but the problem is the problem came down to finding solution to $r_{n}=\frac{r_{n-1}*400+100+r_{n-1}*40000}{40000}$, $r_{0}=\frac{2500}{40000}$. But the problem is Ive only seen results for arithmetic series and geometric but this a mix and I couldn't find any answers

Comment: But I did make this R code if this helps for this specific example, int=0.0625
i=1

while(int<1)
{
 int=(int*400+100+int*40000)/(40000)
 i=i+1
}

Comment: Hi Kamster, thanks for your efforts, it is really appreciated. At least I can produce, albeit in a horribly long winded way, an accurate figure by iteration. Hopefully the next time you hear of this will be on the news with thousands of people buying their houses in 11 years 8 months without a mortgage!